# Finding the Normal and Tension on a body on an inclined plane

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

Imagine an inclined plane with a body with mass $m$ on it. The body is connected to a rigid wall via string (Assume no slack and the string is parallel to slope). I want to find the normal reaction on mass m and tension in the string (massless string), assuming the system is in equilibrium.

Comment: Hello! Please read [How do I ask homework questions on Physics Stack Exchange?](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As the given system is in equilibrium, the net force acting on the body is zero. The forces acting on the body are gravitational force vertically downward, normal force perpendicular to wedge, and tension force along the surface of the wedge. Let angle of inclination of the inclined plane is *x*, then the component of gravitational force along the plane is *mg*Sin(*x*). So the **tension in the string is also *mg*Sin(*x*)** along the plane upwards. The component of gravitational force perpendicular to the plane is *mg*Cos(*x*) and normal force balances it. So the **normal force is *mg*Cos(*x*)** perpendicular to the plane downwards.